# Post To Instagram screen on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, instagram

I am trying to make sharing from my app to Instagram easy. And what I want is to get to the screen that is depicted on the screenshot below. I've tried instagram-stories://share deeplink and I've read thorugh all these docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

However, whatever I do, when the url scheme action fires it goes directly into sharing the image into the story. What am I missing here?

[image]

Here is my code excerpt:

```
           if let image = image {
                guard let urlScheme = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share"),
                    let imageData = image.pngData() else {
                    return
                }

                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(urlScheme) {
                    let pasterboardItems = [["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage": imageData]]
                    let pasterboardOptions = [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*5)]

                    UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasterboardItems, options: pasterboardOptions)

                    UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to open Instagram app using the following url:
`instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=` and pass as a parameter `PHAsset.localIdentifier`.
For some reason this hook isn't listed anywhere in the documentation ‍♂️

But in order to receive a local identifier for your image/video, you must first save the image/video to user's photo library.
So the final code would look like this

```
let videoFileUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path/to/my/video")!
var localId: String?
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoFileUrl)
    localId = request?.placeholderForCreatedAsset?.localIdentifier
}, completionHandler: { success, error in
    // completion handler is called on an arbitrary thread
    // but since you (most likely) will perform some UI stuff
    // you better move everything to the main thread.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard error == nil else {
            // handle error
            return
        }
        guard let localId = localId else {
            // highly unlikely that it'll be nil,
            // but you should handle this error just in case
            return
        }

        let url = URL(string: "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=\(localId)")!
        guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
            // handle this error
            return
        }
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
})
```

Comment: Apple block in App Store app which using saving feature from Instagram. Can you provide code without saving?

Comment: @ucelme i am using same method for my app to share on Instagram, can you please let me know if comes across any solution. i have not launched yet on app store.

Answer (score 1):

1. assume that your `image` is "png"
2. assume that you allowed
   "instagram-stories" in your info.plist (key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`)